# Building Visual Studio project starts with long wait for Installing Packages

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio 2015 web site project that occasionally takes an excessive amount of time to install packages before it does the build. It's a project who's updates I have to unpack from a zip each time because they refuse to deliver it as a repo. Is there anything I can do to check for any issues that might be hanging it up or even have these preloaded?

After watching the Output feed more closely, most of the delay is being caused by npm trying to check node for updates. It seems to make progress only to stop at irregular intervals for extended amounts of time. I still don't know what keeps holding it up though.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I've found does let you preload the node files as long as you remember to do it before running the build or opening the project.

Go to the site's node_modules directory in command line and directly run the update.

```
...\node_modules>npm install
```

This finishes quickly and Visual Studio seems to accept it and doesn't get bogged down trying to update the files itself.